# How to dispatch_group_wait for dispatch_group_async inside an asynchronous block

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have code that looks something like this:

```
[SVProgressHUD show];
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times
                completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, ...) {
                    dispatch_group_async(queueGroup, queue, ^{
                        // Do stuff
                });
}];

dispatch_group_wait(queueGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

Basically, display a loading animation HUD and start generating image thumbnails from an asset, then once it's done hide the HUD. I'm using a dispatch group since i want to make sure all the thumbnails are generated before i hide the HUD.

But when i run it, the HUD gets dismissed immediately. I'm guessing this is because of the asynchronous nature of the `generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes: completionHandler:`--`dispatch_group_wait` is called before the first `dispatch_group_async` inside the completionHandler.

What is a graceful way to get around this situation? Thanks.

Comment: The completion block won't get called until all the images have been loaded, why not just put it in there? The dismissal that is.

Comment: Can you post the implementation of the function: 
generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes ?

Comment: @PeterFoti Sorry about the confusion, the way generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes works is the completionHandler gets called for each thumbnail generated, which means `dispatch_group_wait` will be called every time a thumbnail is generated. We only want it to be called once, don't we?

Comment: Here's the function. Basically you pass an NSArray of timestamps and it the handler gets called for each thumbnail generated, asynchronously: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAssetImageGenerator/generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:completionHandler:

Comment: But you know the number of images to be created, so you can dismiss the HUD when the completion block is called for the last image.

Answer (score 9):

Think of this method as a static counter available to threads, so when you enter a group the counter increments, and when that block returns, decrements...

When that counter is 0, it will call a block to invoke

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

while(someCondition)
{
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
   [SomeClassThatLoadsOffTheInternet getMyImages:^{

        // do something with these.
        dispatch_group_leave(group);

    });
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    // do something when all images have loaded
});
```

Is that what you were thinking of?