# How to notify when multiple block data calls have completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, reactive-cocoa

I am looking to pull in some data via blocks, but I only want to return once all of the data has been retrieved (All of an arbitrary number of call have returned and not gotten errors). I have looked into RAC and dispatch_groups, but have not quite been able to figure this out. The code I'm attempting to execute looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToReturn = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (SPTPartialArtist *partialArtist in artistArray) {
    [SPTRequest requestItemFromPartialObject:partialArtist withSession:self.session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
            [arrayToReturn addObject:object];
        }];
}
return arrayToReturn
```

However, this just returns an empty array because the loop is finishing before any of the data comes in. I'm essentially looking for a way to only return only when the block has been called on each item in the loop, therefore the return array is full of the new objects

Comment: well your approach is not correct. AFAIK this method should not return anything or return a block that will contain data/error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you actually need here is a dispatch_group and a completion block as below:

```
-(void)downloadDataForArtists:(NSArray*)artistsArray withCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray* dataArray))completion
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayToReturn = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dispatch_group_t downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create(); 
    for (SPTPartialArtist *partialArtist in artistArray) {
        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup);
        [SPTRequest requestItemFromPartialObject:partialArtist withSession:self.session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
        [arrayToReturn addObject:object];
        dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup); 
        }];
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (completion) {
            completion(arrayToReturn);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: dispatch_group is the correct non reactive cocoa solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133770/how-to-dispatch-group-wait-for-dispatch-group-async-inside-an-asynchronous-block/20134198#20134198

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just create a method with block parameter? Your code will look like this:

```
- (void)arrayWithBlock:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *array))block
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayToReturn = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (SPTPartialArtist *partialArtist in artistArray) {
        [SPTRequest requestItemFromPartialObject:partialArtist withSession:self.session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
            [arrayToReturn addObject:object];
            if (arrayToReturn.count == artistArray.count) {
                if (block) {
                    block(arrayToReturn);
                }
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that -- what happens if your asynchronous requests complete out-of-order?

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an array (lets say completionArray) in the controller and along with that maintain a count (lets say blockCount) of blocks to be executed for the data download in the controller.

Whenever a particular block completes its execution, the block will add either 1 (for success) or 0 (for failure) in completionArray.

After that the block will check whether the blockCount matches completionArray.count. If they match, it means all the blocks have completed their execution.

Then the block will notify the controller the same.

 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged with `reactive-cocoa`, let's look at the RAC approach.

Your question asks how to turn a series of asynchronous operations into a single synchronous operation. *This is a bad idea*. It's possible, but it will just block the thread you're on. If you're already using RAC, you should manage your asynchronous methods (like this one) using signals, instead of forcing them to be synchronous.

But anyway.

Either way, you want to start by wrapping `requestItemFromPartialObject:withSession:callback:` with a signal-based API. You should probably do this in a category on `SPTRequest`, but for brevity I'm gonna be lazy about it:

```
static RACSignal *request(id<SPTPartialObject> partialObject, SPTSession *session) {
    return [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
        [SPTRequest requestItemFromPartialObject:partialObject withSession:session callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
            if (error) {
                [subscriber sendError:error];
            } else {
                [subscriber sendNext:object];
                [subscriber sendCompleted];
            }
        }];
        return nil;
    }];
}
```

Then what you're really trying to do is take a collection of artists, turn it into a collection of signals, then turn that into a collection of results. Once you have that, you can choose to transform that into an array (the synchronous approach) or return the signal (the right thing to do).

For starters, we want to turn the array of artists into a signal of artists. It makes things easier. You can lift an array into a signal like this:

```
RACSignal *artistSignal = [artistArray.rac_sequence signal];
```

Then turning a signal of one thing asynchronously into a signal of another thing is as easy as:

```
RACSignal *results = [artistSignal flattenMap:^RACSignal *(SPTPartialArtist *partialArtist) {
    return request(partialArtist, self.session);
}];
```

`flattenMap` being an operation that's a little hard to gain intuition for -- it's like `map`, but its transformation block returns a `Signal<T>` instead of a `T`, and then it "unwraps" each signal giving you a `Signal<T>` as the result (instead of a `Signal<Signal<T>>`, as `map` would).

If you *really* want to make this synchronous (you don't), you *can* (but shouldn't) use the `toArray` method:

```
return [results toArray];
```

This will block until all the requests are completed, so if you're doing this you need to make sure you're doing it off the main thread, or your whole app will freeze up.

The right thing to do, though, is to return the signal by itself, and have your callers be aware that this method is asynchronous.

This solution will also order results properly, so you don't run into the ordering problems your current code and some of the other answers have (the results array containing results in the order they came back, not the order requested).

Answer (score 0):

Using dispatch_group is the correct way. The code could be like this:

```
-(void)requestItemsFromArtists:(NSArray *)artistArray completionBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *))block{
  NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray array];
  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
  for(SPTPartialArtist *artist in artistArray){
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [SPTRequest requestItemFromPartialObject:artist withSession:self.session callback:^(NSError *error, id object){
            [items addObject:object];
        }];
    });
  }
 dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(block){
        block(items);
    }
  });
}
```