# Waiting for async function to finish using GCD

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have an async function that queries Parse. I need to wait until all objects from the Parse query have returned before calling my second function. The problem is, I'm using:

```
          var group: dispatch_group_t = dispatch_group_create()

          dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { () -> Void in

                asyncFunctionA() // this includes an async Parse query

            }

          dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) { () -> Void in

                asyncFunctionB() // must be called when asyncFunctionA() has finished

            }
```

...but, `asyncFunctionB()` is getting called before I even have any objects appended to my arrays in `asyncFunctionA()`. Isn't the point of using GCD notify to observe the completion of a prior function? Why isn't that working here?

Comment: you need to enter into the group at the start of your `asyncFunctionA` and leave it when `asyncFunctionA` returns. I have an Obj-c answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133770/how-to-dispatch-group-wait-for-dispatch-group-async-inside-an-asynchronous-block/20134198#20134198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Parse employs the concept of completion block/closures, you need to do the same in your `asyncFunctionA`:

```
func asyncFunctionA(completionHandler: () -> ()) {
    // your code to prepare the background request goes here, but the
    // key is that in the background task's closure, you add a call to
    // your `completionHandler` that we defined above, e.g.:

    gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { success, error in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like your code snippet:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()

dispatch_group_enter(group)
asyncFunctionA() {
    dispatch_group_leave(group)
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    self.asyncFunctionB()
}
```

Note, if function A was really using Parse's asynchronous methods, then there's no need to use `dispatch_async` there. But if you need it for some reason, feel free to add that back in, but make sure the `dispatch_group_enter` occurs *before* to dispatch to some background thread.

Frankly, I'd only use groups if I had a whole bunch of items added to this group. If it really was just B waiting for single call to A, I'd retire the groups entirely and just do:

```
asyncFunctionA() {
    self.asyncFunctionB()
}
```

Comment: Solid. I actually have 3 functions to wait on, so `dispatch_group_enter/leave(group)` worked perfectly there. Note: Make sure `dispatch_group_leave` is called right after your for-loop in a return call, otherwise you may get an exc_breakpoint